# Is there any way to rebind template parameters generally?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose that I have a function template (`foo` in the example), where I know that the type of a variable (`t` in the example) is based on a class template with one parameter. I'd like to declare a new variable (`other` in the example), which uses the same template but with a different template parameter.

If the class template (`Foo`) is my code (so I can modify it freely), I can add an alias template (`Self` in this example), so I can use it to rebind parameters:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo {
    template <typename U>
    using Self = Foo<U>;
};

// bar is a function which returns a Foo (in the general case, it
// can return any type based on a single-parameter template)
template <typename T>
T bar();

template <typename T>
void foo() {
    auto t = bar<T>();

    // declare 'other' using the same template as 't' uses,
    // but with a different (int) template parameter
    typename decltype(t)::template Self<int> other;
}
```

Is it possible to solve this problem generally where I cannot add `Self` to the class template?

(Note: I mean that `foo` has to work with all single-parameter class templates, not just with `Foo`. I cannot add `Self` to all possible class templates that `foo` might use)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more or less trivial using a partial specialization with a template template parameter:

```
template<class T>
class Foo {};

template<class, class>
struct rebind;

template<template<class> class F, class U, class T>
struct rebind<F<U>, T> {
    using type = F<T>;
};

Foo<double> t;
rebind<decltype(t), int>::type other;
static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(other), Foo<int>>);
```